# How can I animate a component from one View to lower the DOM?

Tags: react-native, react-portal

I'm writing a PlayingCard game. I want to animate a card from the Handfan to the cardTable. As soon as the card leavs the Fan View it disappears. How can I animate it smoothly to the middle of the Display what would be higher up in the DOM?

I though maybe it works with react-native-portal?

This is the card:

```
return (
      <View style={styles.outerContainer}>
        <Animated.View style={[styles.playerHandContainer, { width: containerAnimValue.x, //+ widthOffset, 
                              height: containerAnimValue.y }]}>
        {cards.map((card, idx) => {
          const { suit, number } = card

          const { x, y, angle } = coords[idx]
          const originalIndex = originalCards.indexOf(JSON.stringify(card))
          // const styleObject = { left: x + leftOffset, top: y, transform: [{ rotate: Math.round(angle) + 'deg' }]}
          const translationAnimValue = translationAnimationValues[originalIndex]

angle, number, originalIndex')
          const styleObject = { left: translationAnimValue.x, top: translationAnimValue.y, 
                                transform: [{ rotate: spins[originalIndex] }]}
          // the list is necessary because it doesn't give you the same results if you put the object directy in the jsx curlies
          return <AnimatedClassCard onPress={() => this.cardOnPress(card, cards, idx, coords, width, height)} 
                                    card={{ suit, number }} key={originalIndex} style={[styles.playerCards, styleObject]}
                                    renderCard={renderCard}/>

                }
            )
        }
        </Animated.View>
      </View>
```

the card should just move out of the handfan container to the main container without disappearing.